# Proof arithmetic mean is bounded

Tags: algebra-precalculus, statistics

Suppose $A$ is the arithmetic mean of the set of real numbers $S$. How would I go about proving that 
$$\min<A<\max$$
Where $\min$ and $\max$ are the minimal and maximal element of $S$, respectively.

Comment: First off, I think you mean a set of real numbers $S$... Now, $A = \frac{a_1 + \cdots + a_n}{n}$. $min = (1) \cdot min = \frac{n \cdot min}{n}$... Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the right inequality is $\text{min} \le A \le \text{max}$, in case all the numbers are the same.

Let the numbers be $S_1, S_2, \dots S_n$.

Then, we have $A = \dfrac{\sum_{i} S_i}{n} \ge \dfrac{\text{min}(S) \cdot n}{n} = \text{min}(S)$. We may perform a similar calculation for the maximum of the set.

(Note that if the set is infinite but closed, we may perform an analogous calculation, but with integration instead of summation.)

Comment: It doesn't change the answer, but the second $\geq$ could be an $=$.